# numpy array view moving window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this

```
X = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I want to construct a view of the array, grouping its elements in a moving window (of size 4 in my example). My result should look like this :

```
M = numpyp.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [2, 3, 4, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6, 7],
              [5, 6, 7, 8],
              [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

This is called a Hankel matrix, and I can use scipy.linalg.hankel to achieve that, or simply execute :

```
M=numpy.array([X[i:i+4] for i in range(len(X)-3)])
```

But I want to avoid the reallocation.

Is there a manner to have a view in the array X as the Hankel matrix described above without reallocation?

Comment: @Divakar : is it an exact duplicate of the question in the link even if my problem is to avoid memory allocation?

Comment: Did you check out `Approach #2` there? It creates a view. Use `strided_app(X,4,1)` for your case.